# $4a^2+36b^2-4a-12b+2=0$; find $2a+6b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ so that
>   $$4a^2+36b^2-4a-12b+2=0$$
>   Determine $2a+6b$.

I can simplify to an expression that contains the product $ab$, but I can't continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $4a^2 + 36b^2 -4a-12b+2 = (2a-1)^2 + (6b-1)^2 = 0$, so that $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=\frac{1}{6}$, hence $2a+6b = 1+1=2$.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: @5xum  Please post your answer, and I will up vote it.

Comment: Nah, it was the exact same one. The world doesn't need two copies of the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the desired quantity directly, let $s=a+3b$ and eliminate $a$.

$$4(s-3b)^2+36b^2-4(s-3b)-12b+2=4s^2-24bs-4s+72b^2+2=0.$$

Solving for $s$,

$$s=3b+\frac12\pm\frac i2|6b-1|.$$

The only real solution is when the imaginary term vanishes, giving $s=1$, hence $2a+6b=2$.

---

Contrary to the initial hope, you can't do without also solving for $b$, and this approach is a failure.